# Mixing code in C, C++, and Fortran

Tags: c++, c, gcc, fortran, interop

I've been playing around with mixing code in C, C++, and Fortran.  One simple test I have involves a main program in C++ (`cppprogram.C`):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
extern "C" {
  void ffunction_(float *a, float *b);
}

extern "C" {
  void cfunction(float *a, float *b);
}

void cppfunction(float *a, float *b);

int main() {
  float a=1.0, b=2.0;

  cout << "Before running Fortran function:" << endl;
  cout << "a=" << a << endl;
  cout << "b=" << b << endl;

  ffunction_(&a,&b);

  cout << "After running Fortran function:" << endl;
  cout << "a=" << a << endl;
  cout << "b=" << b << endl;

  cout << "Before running C function:" << endl;
  cout << "a=" << a << endl;
  cout << "b=" << b << endl;

  cfunction(&a,&b);

  cout << "After running C function:" << endl;
  cout << "a=" << a << endl;
  cout << "b=" << b << endl;

  cout << "Before running C++ function:" << endl;
  cout << "a=" << a << endl;
  cout << "b=" << b << endl;

  cppfunction(&a,&b);

  cout << "After running C++ function:" << endl;
  cout << "a=" << a << endl;
  cout << "b=" << b << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

...calling procedures in C, C++, and Fortran:

#### C (`cfunction1.c`)

```
void cfunction(float *a, float *b) {
  *a=7.0;
  *b=8.0;
}
```

#### C++ (`cppfunction1.C`)

```
extern "C" {
  void cppfunction(float *a, float *b);
}

void cppfunction(float *a, float *b) {
  *a=5.0;
  *b=6.0;
}
```

#### Fortran (`ffunction.f`)

```
subroutine ffunction(a,b)
a=3.0
b=4.0
end
```

Here are the commands I use to make the object files and link them together:

```
g++ -c cppprogram.C
gcc -c cfunction1.c
g++ -c cppfunction1.C
gfortran -c ffunction.f
g++ -o cppprogram cppprogram.o cfunction1.o cppfunction1.o ffunction.o
```

Here is my error:

```
cppprogram.o: In function `main':
cppprogram.C:(.text+0x339): undefined reference to `cppfunction(float*, float*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I know that internally the compiler sometimes wants underscores appended to the file names, but I thought I had taken care of that.  This can be determined with the `nm` command.  There is a small mistake somewhere...does anyone see it?  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Fortran  2003 provides the ISO C Binding, which specifies to the Fortran compiler that C calling conventions should be used.  If you use this for you multi-language projects, your code will be more portable -- and you won't have to worry about underscores.  See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/fortran-iso-c-binding/info

Comment: @M.S.B. `bind(C)` will be enough here to get rid of the underscore, I think the `iso_c_binding` module will not be necessary. At least the implicit typing used in the code is much larger problem than the possibility of a very uncommon incompatibility of `real` and `float`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update**:

You declare `cppfunction` as `extern "C"` in `cppfunction1.C`, but in `cppprogram.C` you don't declare it as `extern "C"`. Since `main` is `C++` you don't need to declare `cppfunction` as `extern "C"` in `cppfunction1.C` unless you want to be able to call it from C or Fortran.

Remove the `extern "C"` from `cppfunction1.C`.

Comment: `cppfunction` *is* declared before `main`. My guess is that it is using wrong calling convention, because the `extern "C"` is missing. Your note about using headers is valid though.

Comment: It's not the return type that is the issue but the name mangling for the argument types.  The declaration in `cppprogram.C` will be name mangled so that argument overloading can be done because it was declared outside of `extern "C" { ... }`

Comment: I missed the declaration of `cppfunction` in `main`. I've updated my answer accordingly.